# What happens when client closes connection before server is done reading bytes from BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I am reading a file being uploaded over the web and it is being sent through http and we are receiving through a BufferedInputStream. Sometimes we get a timeout exception in the middle of reading from the stream. My working theory is that the connection is being closed from the client before we can process the whole file. The file is in the order of mb.

Does this theory make sense? Does the client need to keep the connection open in order for the server to completely read bytes from the input stream?

Comment: If the client closes, or more exactly if it half-closes the upload direction, your read will get EOF, which depending on the methods you use usually returns a special value (e.g. `read(byte[])` returns -1, `readLine()` returns null) but may throw an EOFException, never a TimeoutException. Therefore this is not what is happening in your case. Timeout either means the client isn't sending all the data, or it is sending or the network is delivering the data too slowly for the timeout you have set. Closing does _not_ cause data loss; _aborting_ can, but in modern networks it isn't likely.

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact error message (exception trace) you get, and the code you're using to send and receive the file? In any case, a time out when the server reads will be related to the time out setting on the server's side of the connection, and it's triggered when the flow of data stops but the connection is still open. It could be that the client is slow or loses network access in the middle of the upload

Answer (score 0):

No good news in that case, data lost will occur.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this theory make sense? Does the client need to keep the connection open in order for the server to completely read bytes from the input stream?

No.

As long as the `BufferedInputStream` has bytes in the buffer, any calls to `read()` / `read(byte[])` / `read(byte[], int, int)` will simply give you data from the buffer and will never even touch the underlying inputstream.

As long as you don't touch said inputstream, it cannot just start throwing exceptions out of the clear blue sky. You need to call *something* on the actual socket inputstream (be it read, close, flush, write - something), in order to get an exception thrown.

What could happen is a mixed mode operation: You call e.g:

```
var raw = socket.getInputStream();
var buffered = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
byte[] b = new byte[1000];
buffered.read(b); // actually reads 4000 bytes into buffer, giving 1000 of them.
// 3000 left in the buffer!
byte[] c = new byte[2000];
buffered.read(c); // works fine and never touches raw. Can't throw.
byte[] d = new byte[2000];
buffered.read(d); // 'mixed mode'
```

Here, in the 'mixed mode' situation, the first 1000 bytes are filled by the buffer, but then `raw.available()` is invoked (source: The actual source code of BufferedInputStream.java); if it returns a non-zero number, then more data is fetched from raw directly; if it is 0, `read()` just returns (`read()` is under no obligation to read ALL the requested bytes; it merely needs to [A] read at least 1, and [B] return how much it did read; usually you want `readNBytes` instead).

However, `in.available()` is allowed to throw. If it does, voila.

However, a normal TCP close would not cause TimeoutExceptions.

A much more likely scenario is the following: Your code is simply not processing the data fast enough. The sending entity at some point is just fed up with it all and refuses to continue to let you hog a file handle and just hangs up on you. If you're already using a buffer, perhaps there's some network equipment in between that is dog slow, or the server is configured with unrealistic expectations of how fast your network connections are.